# Comprobar si una imagen existe en la carpeta

Tags: javascript, ajax, imagen, rutas

Tenemos un portal web en el que cada usuario aparece con un imágen.

En una carpeta tenemos todas las fotos de los usuarios. El nombre de las imágenes es el DNI de cada usuario.

Queremos que si una imagen no existe (la imagen de un usuario), en la imagen de ese usuario aparezca una imagen estándar.

El siguiente código:

```
function (data, type, row, meta) {                              
    return '<img src="../Fotos/' + data.dni + '.jpg" width="64" height="89"  alt=""/>';
}
```

Lo que necesito es que revise si la ruta existe (src="../Fotos/"+data.dni+".jpg") y si no existe se cambie la ruta (esto es fácil).

Lo que no consigo hacer es comprobar si la ruta existe (si la imagen está en la carpeta).

He probado a hacerlo con una llamada ajax a un archivo php pero no me funciona.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el evento `onerror` para cargar una imagen por defecto en caso de que falle la carga:

```js
function cargarImagenes(){
  var img1 = document.getElementById('imagen1');
  img1.onerror = cargarImagenPorDefecto;
  var img2 = document.getElementById('imagen2');
  img2.onerror = cargarImagenPorDefecto;
}

function cargarImagenPorDefecto(e){
  e.target.src= 'https://www.blackwallst.directory/images/NoImageAvailable.png';
}
cargarImagenes();
```

```css
img{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/458/PNG/128/Shy-Minion-icon_43752.png" id="imagen1" />
<img src="https://imagen-noexiste.com/noimage.png" id="imagen2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de la tecnología de servidor que estés usando:

```
- NodeJS: 
const fs = require('fs')
fs.access('ruta del archivo', err => {
 if (err) console.log('El archivo no existe')
})

- Apache u otros servidores corriendo con PHP:
if (file_exists('ruta del archivo')) {} else { echo 'El fichero no existe' }
```